# How to stop auto-generation of log files by cron?

Tags: bash, shell, cron, pywikibot

I have a bot on Marathi language wikipedia. The bot runs from Wikimedi's toolforge server. I have set up a cron job which generates two files: one `.err` and another is `.out`

Following is my the content from my cron file:
`0 9 * * * jsub -release buster -N KiranBOT1 kiranbot1.sh`

The job runs daily. I was away for around a week, and the .err file became around 500 megabytes in size. So I deleted it, and after one run when I checked the newly generated file, it was around 8 megabytes.

It doesn't generate multiple `.err` files, but it keeps adding on the details in the same file, which increases the file size tremendeously. I have created that bot in such a way, that even if I stop editing Wikipedia/stop checking the bot, even then the bot would keep doing its task. In such a scenario, the .err file size would just keep on increasing. I don't want that to happen.

I can live without these .err, and .out files. Is there a way to stop generating these files?

Thanks a lot in advance,
-usernamekiran.

Edit:
The file names are `KiranBOT1.err`, and `KiranBOT1.out`. I apologise, I should have mentioned this in my original question.

Comment: The day you stop generating the logs is the day that you need them...  why not create a dated daily pair of files, and use logrotate to remove after (say) one week?

Comment: yes, that would be a wise idea. I will see if I can do it on that server by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Original throwaway comment now posted as an answer.*

The day you stop generating the logs is the day that you need them...

My suggestion would be create a dated daily pair of files (`KiranBOT1_YYYYMMDD.err`, and `KiranBOT1_YYYYMMDD.out`), and use `logrotate` to remove after (say) one week?

Comment: Apparently, that happens automatically :-| I didn't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check the full names of the files and do something like

```
ln -s /dev/null .err
ln -s /dev/null .out
echo "Warning: .err and .out are symlinks from /dev/null" > README
```